# Does DeltaSpike ConfigResolver pick up runtime chnages

Tags: deltaspike

So I'm looking for CDI property injection and I'm looking at DeltaSpike

http://deltaspike.apache.org/configuration.html

I need to listen to property changes at runtime.
So, if I inject a property like so and then at runtime change the poll interval value in the properties file will this change get picked up?

```
@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "endpoint.poll.interval")
private Integer pollInterval;
```

Comment: it's better to use cdi-events for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the scope of your config source.  If your config source is RequestScoped, it's going to get refreshed with each request.